# Rails Translate SQL raw in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have this SQL query

```
sql = "select mt1.* from mail_templates as mt1 join mail_templates as mt2 where mt1.template_id = mt2.id AND mt1.technical_name='#{name}' AND mt2.festival_id=#{festival}"
```

If I execute this query with `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql).first` it returns an array and I need to have a MailTemplate ActiveRecord.

I don't know how to do it.

Thanx for your help

Comment: You might want to give [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=ruby+array) a look.

Answer (score -2):

I found the solution by using

```
sql = "select mt1.* from mail_templates as mt1 join mail_templates as mt2 where mt1.template_id = mt2.id AND mt1.technical_name='#{name}' AND mt2.festival_id=#{festival}"
MailTemplate.find_by_sql(sql)
```